# iPhone can't access local website hosted on IIS

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, iphone, iis-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure IIS on my PC so that other machines can access it](https://superuser.com/questions/218889/how-to-configure-iis-on-my-pc-so-that-other-machines-can-access-it)

I have a laptop (with Windows 7 on it), an iPhone, and  a Wi-Fi access point.

I have hosted a local website on my local IIS7 and want to access it from my iPhone.

My laptop and iPhone both are connected with the Wi-Fi device and can use internet, but my iPhone was unable to get it.